# HoughLines invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

Hi am using **HoughLines Method** to detect lines from a camera, i've filtered my image "imgProcessed" using **ROI** it means getting just the black objects to make the tracking simple, then when i intend to use the HoughLines method it gives me an error that my "CannyEdges" has some **invalid arguments**, here's my code :

```
Image<Gray, Byte> gray = imgProcessed.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
        Gray cannyThreshold = new Gray(180);
        Gray cannyThresholdLinking = new Gray(120);
        Gray circleAccumulatorThreshold = new Gray(120);
        Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = gray.Canny(cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);


        LineSegment2D[] lines = imgProcessed.cannyEdges.HoughLines(
                                cannyThreshold,
                                cannyThresholdLinking,
                                1,                  //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
                                Math.PI / 45.0,     //Angle resolution measured in radians.
                                50,                 //threshold
                                100,                //min Line width
                                1                   //gap between lines
                                )[0];               //Get the lines from the first channel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my code & it works, i've devised it in two parts : the first part where i've detected the canny edges rather then use the **HoughLines method** to detect it automatically, and the 2nd where i've used the **HoughLinesBinary method** rather than **HoughLines** with  less arguments, here is the code :

```
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray1 = imgProcessed.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
        Image<Gray, Byte> cannyGray = gray1.Canny(120, 180);
        imgProcessed = cannyGray;

        LineSegment2D[] lines = imgProcessed.HoughLinesBinary(
                                1,                  //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
                                Math.PI / 45.0,     //Angle resolution measured in radians.
                                50,                 //threshold
                                100,                //min Line width
                                1                   //gap between lines
                                )[0];               //Get the lines from the first channel
```